# How to count the number of list in list items in Django templates

Tags: django

Here is my template code:

```
{% for category in category_list %}
{% if category.age >= 18 and category.age <= 35 %}
{{ category.age }} // <----- How to count this list?
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

category.age is a list of person from age 18 to 35. How can I count the number of person with age 18 to 35?

Here is my model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
      last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
      first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
      middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
      affix_name = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
      date_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=False)

      @property
      def age(self):
          if self.date_birth is None:
             self.date_birth = 0
          else:
             return int((datetime.date.today() - self.date_birth) // datetime.timedelta(days=365.2425))

     def __str__(self):
          return "%s" % self.last_name
```

Here my view:

```
category_list = Person.objects.all()
context = {'category_list': category_list}
return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it directly inside your views.py

```py
age_between_18_35 = [] # create an empty list
age_between_18_35_count = None
other_age = []

category_list = Person.objects.all()

for object in category_list:
    if object.age >= 18 and object.age <=35:
        age_between_18_35.append(object.age)
    else:
        other_age.append(object.age)

age_between_18_35_count = len(age_between_18_35)

context = {'category_list': category_list, 'age_count': age_between_18_35_count}
return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

In your template

```html
{{ age_count }}
```

Comment: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: try int(object.age) and let me know

Comment: when you did `{{ category.age }}` what was the result?

Comment: when I try {{ category.age }} it display all ages from 18 to 35. What I want to achieve is to display how many person ages 18 to 35 sir.

Comment: int(object.age) display "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"

Comment: Sir kimhong Muong, thank you very much your code works. I really appreciate your help. There are invalid inputs in the database that is why it is not working when I copied your code but I found out later that there are null values in date_birth. Now its working smoothly. Thank sir and Godbless!..

Comment: @ChristianRagus you can mark the answer as accepted for future search

Answer (score 0):

`{{ category.age.count }}` if it's a QuerySet, or `{{ cateogyr.age|length }}` will work for anything.

Comment: You will need to provide more information in order to get a helpful response. What happens when you try?

Comment: Sir if I use {{ category.age|length }} the output is 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .........

Comment: What about just {{ category|length }} then

Comment: {{ category|length }} output is 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ......

Comment: Could you please show how do you create categories.